# Is it possible to get Safari of Mountain Lion running on Lion?

Tags: macos, safari

I noticed the difference in Safari 6.0 in Lion and Mountain Lion. In Lion it is Safari v 6.0 (7536.25) where as in Mountain Lion it is 8536.25.. The way safari works is also a bit different, for instance the tab view. I liked it when I used it, but I want the same in my Lion as well.. Can I copy the Safari.app from my office laptop running Mountain Lion and put it in my 13" MBP running Lion? Would this work?

Comment: Have you looked a webkit nightly builds? I don't have a Lion machine to test on but it might give you the features you are looking for:  http://nightly.webkit.org/

Comment: oh, I haven't come across this website thus far. Will take a look. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Let us know if it works. If it does I'll re-submit as an answer.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't. It is still 
Version 6.0 (7536.25, 537+) and not Version 6.0 (8536.25).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no - Safari uses quite a few system-level frameworks that are vastly different between those OSes.

Comment: oh thanks for the reply.. So I probably have to upgrade to mountain lion then

Comment: To standardize Safari 6, yeah, that would be easiest - imho, Mountain Lion is a real improvement over Lion.  (That tip about a nightly WebKit is a good idea too, I hadn't considered that.)

Comment: No, I tried it. It doesn't have the features found in Mountain Lion :(